# Binding to grids in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, grid

I've just begun learning Silverlight (though I have 3 years C# experience).
I'm trying to output a grid that will be used in a work timetracking application.
I have a list of objects, each object looks like this

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public int TaskId {get;set;}
    public int WeekId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date  {get;set;}
    public decimal TimeSpent {get;set;}
    public string TaskName {get;set;}
}
```

Obviously I could just set a grid's item source to a list of these objects and I'd end up with them output in some sort of grid.
However I am wanting to output as grid with taskNames down the left handside and days of the week across the top. (i.e. just displaying one week at a time).
Each cell would then just output a timeSpent value.

I've managed to do this in ASP.Net MVC with just html table etc though I'm not really sure where to start with a silverlight version.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated, (i.e. any pointers on what to read up on etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with my own solution, I just created a separate class that represented each row.
The class has properties monday, tuesday wednesday etc that contained one of the objects described above.

Comment: I was about to suggest that.  Do the translation in code and use data binding to a DataGrid (not a Grid, right?)

Comment: Yeah DataGrid not grid.
Solution works ok, I have an IDictionary<System.DayOfWeek, TimeSlotItem>, the properties that the grid binds to just point at this dictionary and only expose the time field.